# error: no '__________' member function declared in class '_______'

Tags: c++

I regard myself as a fairly novice c++ programmer and I have never experienced this error before.

I'm simply trying to create a class for my function but all my std:: prefixed functions declared in my header file are not being recognised

```
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>

class Person
{
    public:
        Person();
        std::string getName();  //return first name
        std::string getSurname();//return surname
        int getWeight();    //return weight
        int getBirthYear(); //return birthyear


    private:
//self explanatory member variables but need to be accessible to patient
        std::string m_name;
        std::string m_surname;
        int m_weight;
        int m_birthYear;
};

#endif
```

.cpp

```
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person()
{
    m_name = "name";
    m_surname = "surname";
    m_weight = 0;
    m_birthYear = 0;
    return;
}

//returns m_name
std::string Person::getName()   
{
    return m_name;
}

//returns m_surname
std::string Person::getSurname()
{
    return m_surname;
}

//returns persnon's weight
int Person::getWeight()
{
    return m_weight;
}   

//returns the person's birth year
int Person::getBirthYear()
{
    return m_birthYear;
}
```

main

```
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
//comments
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//  Person matt;
//  cout << matt.getName() << endl;
//  cout << matt.getSurname() << endl;
//  cout << matt.getWeight() << endl;
//  cout << matt.getBirthYear() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error I'm receiving

```
g++ Main.cpp Person.h Person.cpp -o test
Person.cpp: In constructor ‘Person::Person()’:
Person.cpp:17:2: error: ‘m_name’ was not declared in this scope
Person.cpp:18:2: error: ‘m_surname’ was not declared in this scope
Person.cpp: At global scope:
Person.cpp:35:29: error: no ‘std::string Person::getName()’ member function declared in class ‘Person’
Person.cpp:41:32: error: no ‘std::string Person::getSurname()’ member function declared in class ‘Person’
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? This exact same std:: formatting has worked for me before but for some reason now only the std::string functions aren't recognised when trying to create a simple Person class.

Comment: What's the header doing in your build command? And what do people have against constructor initializer lists?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way I've been taught to program and its preferred by my tutors/markers as its easier for them to skim

Comment: Well your tutors are wrong about this. Ask for your money back.

Comment: Please provide the actual code that is failing to compile. The first error message refers to line 17, but it is not line 17 in what you included in your question.

Comment: Oops, shouldn't have removed the comments...

Comment: This compiles file for me/

Comment: My best stab at the problem is honestly the build command including the header, but I've only built anything like that maybe once, so I don't really know what kind of errors to expect from it.

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error minus the .h in the build command, you aren't getting errors user93353?!

Comment: Can it be something like namespace? I always use namespaces, so I don't know how not having a namespace behaves...

Comment: The only way I've been shown is to set the namespace as std in the main.cpp and prefix all couts or string declarations with std:: that are located in files separate to the main, I wouldn't know how else to do it

Comment: (this error is driving me crazy, I'm supposed to be implementing a complex hospital administration system as an assignment but I can't even get the person class defined!)

Comment: Do you by any chance have any `.pch` files in your project directory? Including the header in the build command is only done for precompiled headers, so you might just have a precompiled older version of `Person.h`.

Comment: I have a Person.h.gch? I will remove that and try again

EDIT - You're a genius hvd, I never would've seen that or even knew it was a possible problem that could exist! Thankyou!!!!

Comment: In any case, you are not compiling the code you have shown here, because that looks fine. Maybe you're in the wrong directory, mixing old and new versions of your code, or you simply forgot to save the file you have open in your editor.

Comment: The precompiled header was the issue.  Out of curiosity, how did I even make that?

Comment: When you typed `g++ Main.cpp Person.h Person.cpp` it generated `Person.h.gch` for you. The question is _why did it not get updated when you rebuild your code_?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the comments:

> ```
> g++ Main.cpp Person.h Person.cpp -o test
> ```

As chris pointed out, it is unusual to include the header files in the compile command line. A slightly different invocation that you probably used earlier:

> ```
> g++ -c Main.cpp Person.h Person.cpp
> ```

creates `Main.o`, `Person.o`, but also a `Person.h.gch` precompiled header. The precompiled header isn't regenerated with your current build command, but is still used, so changes to `Person.h` do not get picked up.